# Injectivity in the zero homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm struggling with following step in an excercises about Mayer-Vietoris sequences:

In one step the solution says this map is injective since $A \cap B$ is path-connected:

$$ H_0(A \cap B) \stackrel{i_*^{A} \oplus i_*^{B}} \longrightarrow H_0(A) \oplus H_0(B)$$

What I've been thinking is that as $A \cap B$ is path-connected we get $H_0(A \cap B) \simeq \mathbb Z[\alpha]$ with $\alpha$ our prefered generator. My idea then was that this map is injective since we map just multiples of the generator to each summand in the target and so the kernel must be trivial. But I'm not quite sure about this argument.

I'd appreciate if someone could elaborate on my idea and tell me wether it works or not and if it does, how one may formulate it better in order for me to believe my own words.

Comment: I am not sure about the context, but what you wrote seems reasonable. (One exception is when $A \cap B = \varnothing$, but in such case the kernel of $i_*^A \oplus i_*^B$ is also obviously trivial.)

Comment: Well I'm computing the singular homology of the real projective space $\mathbb R P ^2$. So yes, $A \cap B$ is not empty. In my sample solution they just stated this fact without any further details so I believe it has to be an argument of this kind.

Comment: And I believe your argument is very valid. I'm not sure what you're not sure about your argument :)

Comment: Everytime around exams sessions I start doubting my own ideas more than usual;)

Comment: What do I do know that this has been clarified? How do I close a thread?

Comment: You can write up your own answer and accept it. (You can make it community's answer too, I believe.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly disagree with you saying that it is a proof, in fact it is not! The map $H_0(A\cap B)\rightarrow H_0(A)\oplus H_0(B)$ takes $n[\alpha]\mapsto(n[i_A\circ\alpha],n[i_B\circ\alpha])$. Since every $H_0$ is free, in particular torsion free, it suffices to show that $[i_A\circ\alpha]$ is nonzero, the argument being similar for $[i_B\circ\alpha]$. Write $\alpha=\sum_{x\in A\cap B} n_x x$; then $i_A\circ\alpha=\sum_{x\in A\cap B} n_x x$. Assume by contradiction that this is $\partial\beta=\sum_{i\in I} m_i(\sigma_i(1)-\sigma_i(0))$ for a $1$-simplex $\beta=\sum_{i\in I} m_i \sigma_i$ in $A$. Then we still have $\alpha=\partial\tilde{\beta}$, where $\tilde{\beta}$ is the $1$-simplex obtained from $\beta$ by dropping all $\sigma_i$ that have $\sigma_i(1)\notin A\cap B$ or $\sigma_i(0)\notin A\cap B$ and all $\sigma_i$ that are loops. But the we may as well take the $\sigma_i$ to be in $A\cap B$, as $A\cap B$ is path-connected. This shows that $\alpha$ is a $1$-boundary, contradicting its definition.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, I tried to give a proof in a similiar fashion but was not able to find the contradiction! Secondly, I think we know each other as I don't really believe you're my professor?:)

Comment: No I am not, i just took his course 2 years ago and thought if I answer here I might as well troll you a bit :D

Comment: Fair enough, as long as you answer my questions I'm more than happy to encounter you on this page in the future! merci ;)